# Tensorflow not getting installed with pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I keep getting errors like;

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from
versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0
 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0
```

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0
rc4 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0rc4
```

I have tried searching for a solution since 4 to 5 hours. I am trying to install it in a virtualenv file.

This has never happened before.
What am I doing wrong?

---

Pip version: **20.2.3**

Pip3 version: **20.2.3**

Python version: **Python 3.7**

Windows: **8.1 64 bit**

Tensorflow version I want to install: **2.x+**

Comment: Yes, please read my question I included my operating system and version

Comment: What commands are you running that are giving you these errors?

Comment: Please provide more info about your system. Are you using python 3? Are you able to install other packages using pip? Which command did you use, exactly?

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy I tried pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0 and pip install tensorflow and also tried using pip3 none of these work 

@ YakovDan Sorry i forgot to include that, I am using Python 3.7 version. I used Pip3 and pip with install --upgrade and without upgrade

Comment: Please make sure that you're using a 64 bit python interpreter. Run the following script:
import platform
platform.architecture()[0]

it should return '64bit'

Comment: @YakovDan Thank you for telling me that, I just ran that line and it returned 32bit, I will install 64 bit interpreter now. For installing it should I delete the 32 bit interpreter? Or will it auto arrange stuff if I download 64 bit?

Comment: It would be best uninstall the 32bit version and install the 64 bit version only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the PIP [tensorflow file listing it should work](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files). Are you are sure you are using a 64-bit python interpreter? If your python interpreter is 32 bit for some reason, it's going to need a 32 bit package.

The packages are not built for Windows 32 bit.

If this is your problem, you should install a 64 bit version of the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that your python installation is 64 bit by using the following script:

```
import platform
platform.architecture()[0]
```

the script should return '64bit'.  if not, install the correct version.
Also, if you wish to use tensorflow 2.2 and above, upgrade to python 3.8 or higher.

Answer (score -1):

TensorFlow is compiled with recent processor. I had problems with this and I had to verify the processor flags (and recompile myself, pff).
Windows 8.1 is surely obsolete